# How do you pause a thread until a condition becomes true without busy waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, listeners, busy-waiting

How do you pause a thread until a condition becomes true without busy waiting?
For example, suppose I'm checking to see whether

> playerOne.isWalking()

Is going to be true and I want to run some code when it does become true. Again suppose playerOne is an instance of the class Player which then has the function isWalking(). I do not have access to the what makes isWalking() become true. So everytime I want to check to see if isWalking() is true, I have to call the method from an instance of player explicitly.

I've tried using Wait/Notify in synchronized blocks but that wouldn't ever work because I would have to manually notify the Thread to wake up when isWalking() becomes true and I don't know when it will become true.

I've tried using the observer pattern to make Player a subclass of observable so that I can call the update method when isWalking() becomes true but again I don't know when that will happen.

I've even tried using Propertys but that wouldn't work either.

Is this even possible to check without busy-waiting? Constantly polling and calling that function to see if it is true, then if it is true, execute the code.

This was a bad solution I made involving busy-waiting:

[Busy-Waiting solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3VnN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlaying problem is that you use a *getter* method to aquire an information and act on it. The principle which is violated here is *Tell, don't ask!*.

The OO whay to solve this is to introduce an *interface* (e.g.:  `PlayerMovingListener`).

The player class would hold an instance of an object implementing that interface (or a list of them). As soon as the player starts walking it calls the `isMoving()` method defined in the interface implemented by the (or all) listener object(s) held by the player.
<sup>Most likely is triggered by a setter method in your current `Payer` implementation.</sup>

Comment: I appreciate the quick response.I don't have access to any setter if there was one in the current implementation of Player from the API I'm using.

`public boolean isInCombat() { /* compiled code */ }`

isInCombat() is the isWalking() function I was talking about, just renamed for sake of clarity.

So is there any options left?

Comment: *"I don't have access to any setter if there was one in the current implementation of Player from the API I'm using."* - You cannot implement the listener pattern on one side only. The `Player` class must provide the infrastructure to handle the listeners. IMHO your program is *broken by design*.

Comment: It's broken by design. That answers it!